# Why can I std::move elements from a const vector?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics

Why does the following code compile?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  std::vector<int> bar = {1, 2, 3};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;
    const Foo& foo2 = foo1;
    
    std::vector<int> target;
    
    std::move(foo2.bar.begin(), foo2.bar.end(), std::back_inserter(target));

    return 0;
}
```

The documentation of [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) says

> After this operation the elements in the moved-from range will still
> contain valid values of the appropriate type, but not necessarily the
> same values as before the move.

So this can actually change the object foo2 even though it's declared const. Why does this work?

Comment: You are allocating memory for Foo struct and then marks it as `const`, so you are preventing to change the reference of that variable. Since `vector<>` points to the another block of memory you can tweak it on your own. If you want to prevent that vector for changes mark it as const: `const vector<int> nums {1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @yemo Not sure that explains the whole story. I can simplify the example code [further](https://godbolt.org/z/qaEfsvGjz). Even when `bar` is a `const std::vector<int>` the `std::move` is allowed.

Comment: The "not necessarily" is a general statement, but it may not apply to specific scenarios. For example "The autographed item you receive may not necessarily be identical to the one on display." But you say "Aha, but in my case, I know that the item is one-of-a-kind, and the only item in existence is the display item. Does the 'not necessarily' mean that the store has the power of resurrection, can bring the celebrity back from the dead, get them to autograph one more item, and then sell that one to me?"

Comment: @nemo, you shouldn't be able to mutate a containers elements using a const reference to the container (barring the use of `mutable`). Similarly, a struct being const transfers that property to its content. So indeed, that question is very justified in my opinion!

Answer (score 27):

> So this can actually change the object foo2 even though it's declared const. Why does this work?

The `std::move` algorithm is *allowed* to move the input elements, *if it can*.

For each input element, it executes `*dest = std::move(*from)`, where `dest` and `from` are the output and input iterators. Since `from` dereferences to a constant object, `std::move(*from)` creates an rvalue reference `const int&&`. Since `int`s don't have user defined constructors, the assignment to `*dest` actually results in a copy construction that is defined by the language.

If your elements were of a class type `T` with user-defined copy and move constructors, overload resolution would have to select the copy constructor (`T(const T&)`) instead of a move constructor (`T(T&&)`) because `const` lvalue reference can bind to a `const` rvalue and non-`const` rvalue reference can't (as that would require casting away the `const`).

The bottom line is that `std::move` (the algorithm with iterators) is performing a move operation, which may or may not invoke a move constructor or assignment. If the move constructor or assignment *is* invoked, and that move *is destructive* on the source, then the algorithm will modify the source elements. In other cases, it will simply perform a copy.

Comment: @Evg The question and the answer is primarily talking about the `std::move` algorithm taking iterators, not the single object `std::move`. Next, the answer does not contradict what you're saying re. function that actually performs the move.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I forgot about `std::move` that takes iterators. Upvoted.

Answer (score 9):

To demonstrate Andrey Semashev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294070/4358570) with examples, consider this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct movable
{
    movable() = default;
    
    movable(const movable&) = delete;
    movable& operator=(const movable&) = delete;

    movable(movable&&) = default;
    movable& operator=(movable&&) = default;
};

struct copyable
{
    copyable() = default;
    
    copyable(const copyable&) = default;
    copyable& operator=(const copyable&) = default;

    copyable(copyable&&) = delete;
    copyable& operator=(copyable&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    // original example
    const std::vector<int> si;
    std::vector<int> ti;
    
    std::move(si.begin(), si.end(), std::back_inserter(ti)); // OK

    // example 2
    const std::vector<copyable> sc;
    std::vector<copyable> tc;
    
    std::move(sc.begin(), sc.end(), std::back_inserter(tc)); // OK

    // example 3
    const std::vector<movable> sv;
    std::vector<movable> tv;
    
    std::move(sv.begin(), sv.end(), std::back_inserter(tv)); // ERROR - tries to use copy ctor

    return 0;
}
```

Even though `copyable` doesn't have a move constructor, example 2 compiles with no error, as `std::move` picks copy constructor here.

On the other hand, example 3 fails to compile because the move constructor of `movable` is negated (better word?) by the constness of `sv`. The error you get is:

```
error: use of deleted function 'movable::movable(const movable&)'
```

Here is a complete [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cba475914e8f8650).

---

**UPDATE**

Step-by-step explanation:

1. Since our type is `const std::vector<T>`, its [`vector::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) function returns [`const_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types).
2. [`const_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types) when dereferenced inside [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm, returns `const T&`.
3. [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm uses [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) function internally, eg:

   ```cpp
   // taken from cppreference.com
   while (first != last) *d_first++ = std::move(*first++);
   ```
4. [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) function in its turn returns:

   ```cpp
   // taken from cppreference.com
   static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`
   ```

   So, for `const T&` it returns `const T&&`.
5. Since we don't have a constructor or `operator=` defined with `const T&&` parameter, overload resolution picks the one that takes `const T&` instead.
6. Voila.

Comment: That's kind of unexpected for me but when I used msvc 19.29 the compilation failed for the second example as well saying that I attempted to reference a deleted function copyable::copyable(copyable &&). Not the case for other compilers.

Comment: After reading some answers here I think that's correct behaviour. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/56242112/197953

Comment: @deephace MSVC would be wrong in this case because move constructor of `copyable` is not used in this code. It must be discarded during overload resolution.

Comment: According to the answer(link) above the move constructor is not discarded because it actually used declared, so it takes part in overload resolution, but because it marked as deleted the compilation error pops up. Am I being wrong with that?

Comment: @deephace Overload resolution takes place before the function is used. As long as the deleted function is not actually selected, it being in the overload candidate set is not an error. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions). As an example, this is what allows movable-only types, like `std::unique_ptr`, to work. For such types, copy constructor is defined as deleted, and when you perform a move operation, both copy and move ctors are considered as candidates, and the move ctor is selected. Discarded deleted copy ctor does not cause an error.

Comment: @deephace this might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595207/4358570

Comment: @deephace I've also added step-by-step explanation to my answer.

Comment: @InnocentBystander thanks for the explanation, I think I lost "const" in my reasoning, but it is not clear why msvc did it too.

Comment: @deephace because it's buggy :P I believe Herb Sutter was saying they are going to ditch it in favor of Clang. Don't quote me on that though :)